# Counting Prolog elements that meet a certain requirement

Tags: prolog

I am working through sample questions while studying using SWI-Prolog. This isn't a homework question, just exam revision using practice questions.

In this question I have a number of provided structures (dept) which includes a list within it, and I have to find **the initial and surname of any head curator in a department that contains a total of 2 or more staff members with early history or modern history as their specialism.**

**The following Prolog database represents departments in a museum.**

```
% A museum department is represented by the structure:
% dept(Area, Head_curator, Deputy_curator, Floor_staff).
%
% Floor_staff is a (possibly empty) list of staff structures and excludes
% the staff for Head_curator and Deputy_curator.
%
% Structures representing staff take the form:
% staff(Initial, Surname,
% cv(Specialism,Second_specialism,Years_employed)).

... Removed db entries that don't satisfy the question

dept(history,staff(d,steele,cv(early_history,modern_history,40)),
  staff(d,owen,cv(modern_history,early_history,35)),
  [staff(c,freud,cv(early_history,modern_history,30))]).
```

I am finding it very difficult to determine how to ensure that at least two of the Head OR the Deputy OR any member of the floor staff has a 1st or 2nd specialisation in early or modern history. I have created the following rules to extract this information:

```
head_curator(X) :- dept(_,X,_,_).
deputy_curator(X) :- dept(_,_,X,_).
floor_staff(X) :- dept(_,_,_,List), member(X,List).

exists(X) :-
   head_curator(X);
   deputy_curator(X);
   floor_staff(X).

first_specialism((staff(_,_,cv(S,_,_,_)),S).
second_specialism((staff(_,_,cv(_,S,_,_)),S).
```

And I have written PROLOG below to extract the head curator's Initial and Surname - however, I am unsure of how to implement a 'count' to ensure any two people have the required specialism

```
q2(Initial,Surname) :-
  dept(_,HeadCurator,_,List),
      % forcing the same dept to be checked
      HeadCurator = exists(staff(Initial,Surname,_)),
      % check first and second specialisations
      % somehow iterate through each person in this dept and 
      % stop once requirement reaches two people
      %
      % e.g. (first_specialisation(X) = modern_history;
      % first_specialisation(X) = early_history;)
      %
      % (second_specialisation(X) = modern_history;
      % second_specialisation(X) = early_history;)
```

I have attempted to flesh out the pseudocode outlining what I WOULD attempt as a solution to let you know that I have thought about it! I am just unsure of how to implement checking:

1. That numerous people have that 1st or 2nd specialisation
2. Returning true once two people are determined to have that specialisation

Comment: you can use setof/3 and checking the length of result is >= 2

Comment: Note that @CapelliC's setof/3 is not needed: To say, there are at least two, it suffices to say `exists(X), exists(Y), dif(X,Y)` (plus some extra goals)